# How to implement ondraw after httprequest to database

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httprequest, ondraw

I'm new on Android development and I have been struggling on how to draw some graphics after a HTTP request to a Mysql database. I have looked into SyncTask, custom View and onDraw method but I must be missing something because I just can't get it to work. Basically the http request selects some records from the db (I got that working) and I need to create a graph with the data. The http request is an asynchronous process so by the time the http request is done, the onDraw method got executed with no data, that's why I started looking into SyncTask but I can't manage to pass the array that stores the data to be drawn from the onPostExecute method. Any help would be greatly appreciated and if you can point to some sample code that would be great. Thank you

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that I found online and I have been trying to make it work, so far I can get the data, to simplify it I'm only working with the field location, and I want to drawtext location:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "AsyncTestFragment";

    // get some fake data
    private static final String TEST_URL                 = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments";
    //private static final String TEST_URL                   = "http://localhost/~juan/A_get_tanks.php";
    private static final String ACTION_FOR_INTENT_CALLBACK = "THIS_IS_A_UNIQUE_KEY_WE_USE_TO_COMMUNICATE";

    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getContent();
    }

    private void getContent() {
        // the request
        try {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(new URI(TEST_URL));
            RestTask task = new RestTask(getActivity(), ACTION_FOR_INTENT_CALLBACK);
            task.execute(httpGet);
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Getting Data ...", "Waiting For Results...", true);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_FOR_INTENT_CALLBACK));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    /**
     * Our Broadcast Receiver. We get notified that the data is ready, and then we
     * put the content we receive (a string) into the TextView.
     */
    public BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String location;
            // clear the progress indicator
            if (progress != null) {
                progress.dismiss();
            }
            String response = intent.getStringExtra(RestTask.HTTP_RESPONSE);
            try {
                JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray tank_data = mainObject.getJSONArray("tank_data");
                JSONObject tankObj = tank_data.getJSONObject(0);
                location = (String) tankObj.getString("Location");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                location = null;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            new TankView(context, location);
            Log.i(TAG, "RESPONSE = " + location);

        }
    };

}

public class RestTask extends AsyncTask<HttpUriRequest, Void, String>
{
    private static final String TAG = "AsyncRestTask";
    public static final String HTTP_RESPONSE = "httpResponse";

    private Context mContext;
    private HttpClient mClient;
    private String mAction;

    public RestTask(Context context, String action) {
        mContext = context;
        mAction = action;
        mClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    }

    public RestTask(Context context, String action, HttpClient client) {
        mContext = context;
        mAction = action;
        mClient = client;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(HttpUriRequest... params) {
        try {
            HttpUriRequest request = params[0];
            HttpResponse serverResponse = mClient.execute(request);
            BasicResponseHandler handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            return handler.handleResponse(serverResponse);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO handle this properly
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "RESULT = " + result);
        Intent intent = new Intent(mAction);
        intent.putExtra(HTTP_RESPONSE, result);

        // broadcast the completion
        mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

}

package com.alvinalexander.asynctest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            TestFragment testFragment = new TestFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, testFragment).commit();
            setContentView(new TankView(this, ""));
        }
    }

}

public class TankView extends View {

    private String location;
    private Paint _paintTank = new Paint();

    public TankView(Context context, String location) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        init(null, 0);
        this.location = location;
    }

    public TankView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        init(attrs, 0);
    }

    public TankView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        init(attrs, 0);
    }

    public TankView(TestActivity testActivity, String location) {
        super(testActivity);
        this.location = location;

    }

    public TankView(TestActivity testActivity, Object o) {
        super(testActivity, (AttributeSet) o);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        _paintTank.setColor(Color.RED);
        _paintTank.setAntiAlias(true);
        _paintTank.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }



    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (this.location != null) {
            canvas.drawText(this.location, 10, 10, _paintTank);
        }
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#AEECFF">

    <!-- fill the screen with a textview. the app will write text into it. -->

    <com.alvinalexander.asynctest.TankView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```